# xAuth for Java?

Tags: java, xauth

I am looking to write a desktop/cli Java app that interacts with [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth). To do that I need to use xAuth. I was hoping that Spring Security could be used to here however, I can't find any supporting documentation. Can someone point me to some documentation for how to support xAuth in Java? I am open to to using a framework other than Spring Security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best description I've seen of xAuth is on the [twitter site](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth). You've probably found the same by searching online.

As for implementing a client in Java, one approach is to reuse the xAuth pieces of the [Twitter API ME](http://www.twapime.com/). The docs make a point of saying that the "xAuth classes are fully reusable by any other API or app, so you can use it to work with any other xAuth service, besides Twitter. So whether you are looking for just a xAuth lib, Twitter API ME provides it for you."